# Add UIView to back of scene in SpriteKit game

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift2

I am trying to make a advent calendar with a snow affect in swift2. I am using the game template while using SpiteKit.

Here is my code so far:

**GameScene.swift**

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    /*override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            print(location)
        }
    }*/

    func test()
    {
        //Generate Doors

        //Initilization
        var adventDoors = [AdventDoor]()
        let offset = CGVector(dx: 10,dy: 10)
        var size = CGRectMake(offset.dx, offset.dy, 60, 60)

        var ypos:CGFloat = 20
        var xpos:CGFloat = 10
        var index = 0
        var xDoor = AdventDoor(frame: size)
        let randomIdentifier = [Int](1...24).shuffle()
        for _ in 1...4
        {
            for i in 1...6
            {
                size = CGRectMake(xpos, ypos, 60, 60)
                xDoor = AdventDoor(frame: size)
                xDoor.opaque = false
                xDoor.restorationIdentifier = "\(randomIdentifier[index])"
                xDoor.generateDoor()
                adventDoors.append(xDoor)
                print("1...6")
                ypos += 80
                //xpos += 20
                index++

                if i == 6
                {
                    print("Moving to next view")
                }

            }

            xpos += 80
            ypos = 20
        }

        size = CGRectMake(10, 500, 300, 60)
        xDoor = AdventDoor(frame: size)
        xDoor.opaque = false
        xDoor.restorationIdentifier = "\(25)"
        xDoor.generateDoor()
        adventDoors.append(xDoor)


        index = 0

        for door in adventDoors
        {
            index++
            self.view?.addSubview(door)
        }
        print("\(index) doors were added")
    }
}
```

**GameViewController.swift**

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {

            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            //skView.showsFPS = true
            //skView.showsNodeCount = true

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            scene.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            skView.presentScene(scene)

            scene.test()

            //Snow
            let wrappedSnowPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Snow", ofType: "sks")
            if let snowPath = wrappedSnowPath
            {
                let snowEmitter:SKEmitterNode = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(snowPath) as! SKEmitterNode
                let screenBounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
                snowEmitter.position = CGPointMake(screenBounds.width, screenBounds.height)
                scene.addChild(snowEmitter)
            }
        }
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
            return .AllButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .All
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

**AdventDoor.swift** just contains a custom UIView (AdventDoor) along with some more functions

This is what it looks like.

[image]

As you can see, the snow SKEmitterNode particles are behind the AdventDoors and not in front.

How would I get my snow to display in front of the UIView Advent Doors instead of behind?

Comment: @Mr.T same happens when I do `self.view.addSubview(adventDoor)`. What do I need to do to fix this problem?

Comment: @iProgram i recommend you to create SKNode with zPosition bigger than all your nodes (for example 999), give that node size of your scene. And populate that node with your snow. (Also do not forget to give your SKEmitterNodes .targetNode)

Comment: @Darvydas I tried zPosistions, however it didn't work. In the end I created UIView and put a SKView in that way. I then added all the advent doors in the UIView and then added the SKView on top.

Comment: @iProgram so everything is ok now ? :)

Comment: @iProgram what happens if you change the property particleZPosition of the SKEmitterNode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `addsubview` for the door, What you need to do is rearrange how your views are laid out.  What you need is a `UIView` as your main view,  then you add the SKView as a child to the main view.  Then if you want to add the doors in during the scene creation process, you need to do `self.view.superview.insertSubView(door, atIndex:0)` or `self.view.superview.insertSubView(door, belowSubView:self.view)` so that the doors are placed behind the scene subview