# SpriteKit Particle Emitter flickering

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, skemitternode

I have used `SKEmitterNode` to establish snow animation, and set an `SKView` to it, when using this `SKView` inside of a `ViewController`, for some reason the `SKView` is flickering it's background color to black, and back again to normal(set to `clearColor`).

Did anyone have the same experience, and have any thoughts as to how to fix this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33972461/4078517 Have a look

Comment: @Darvydas iProgram had an issue with view placements, I have an issue with the way the Emitter Node works, which causes a black flickering on the View.

Comment: There is the way he did same effect as you whant, and i think he did not have any flickering.